# How to append results from a function and save in a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have been turning around a problem by several days and I can not reach a successful solution to my code using python. I have a dataframe with sets of coordinates, let's say: the whole information of a formula 1 gran prix! Cool, I defined a function that calculate some attributes, for example the distance, the speed or the pits stop times for all the cars. My functions work but I can not find the way in which I have to save the information for all the cars, I can only get my first or my last result in a data frame.

I think that the question is very basic and I only need the correct way to save computed results in a dataframe, when the function is ran by several times. Thanks by your kind responses!

Comment: I think you are looking for `df['new_column'] = df.apply(function)`